# Which motor should I use? High speed, reasonable torque

Tags: motor, servo

I am currently taking on a project of building a small jet engine, and I wanted to know which kind of motor I should use to drive the shaft. Apparently steppers lose torque at higher speeds. Idealy I would like a motor which offers high speed with torque greater than or equal to 4Nm. I know very little about servos. Power consumption is not an issue.

Comment: BLDC at a guess. If you are looking for specific parts, that is what Google is for - shopping q's are off-topic here.

Comment: I suppose "high speed" means something between 4000 and 100,000 RPM. A brushless DC motor would be good for the low end of that range, but perhaps not the high end. An induction motor might be better for some part of that range. A stock motor may not be available for a speed much above 4000 RPM. You need to have a specific RPM requirement before you start looking.

Comment: Why do you think you need a servo motor? I can not think of any reason to drive an engine with a motor except for test and balancing purposes.

Comment: By definition a jet engine burns fuel to produce thrust. Do you want to start a jet engine with an electric motor, or do you actually want to make an electric ducted fan? How fast is 'higher speeds'? Why do you need 4Nm torque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you go back to the drawing board. 
4 Nm torque will translate into an insanely high power output for your engine. I'm assuming here that it's not actually a jet engine, but uses a motor driven blower to compress the air.....these are called Ducted Fan motors, and common as an electric RC model 'jet' engine.

4 Nm is about 11 HP (@20k rpm). That is a very very big motor.
Most large RC ducted fan motors are in the 1-3 HP range and typically run at 20000-45000 rpm.
[Here's](http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLDF15) one that is less than 1 HP for reference.
[image]

These are [BLDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) motors, and like a stepper motor they have multiple phases, in this case normally 3 phase (and they are not like stepper motors in many ways). You could investigate a range of RC motors with your own fan design, but they are very hard to balance, so this should not be taken on lightly.

Comment: NM isn't a unit of power...

Comment: @JonRB. Correct, but from the torque at a given rpm you can calculate the HP rating. Since we know that he's tying to create a fan jet, we know the motor (fan) will be rotating at high speed, I used 20k rpm as a base value. This may help you: http://auto.howstuffworks.com/question622.htm    ....or a calculator for Nm - HP:  http://ncalculators.com/electrical/torque-to-horsepower-calculator.htm

Comment: Believe me when I say I know about motors and motor control. This doesn't change the fact you are using Nm as a unit of power. P=Tw

Comment: @JonRB.I'm happy to hear from someone with more detailed knowledge. But rather than simply criticize my translation of Nm to a required power ....how would you calculate the OP's needs? If you are skilled in this, your knowledge transfer would be very valuable.

Comment: I am actually trying to find if a paper I wrote is in the public domain where I started a jet engine with a wound rotor sync machine. There isn't enough info in the OP to suggest anything as the torque profile during windmill to ignition isn't stated, neither the speed.

Comment: @JonRB. My assumption was that the OP was not looking for a starter motor for a fuel powered jet engine (that would I think have been a very clear requirement). But maybe he can clear that up by providing more detail. Either way, I look forward to your interpretation on an answer.